# masm32, поиск первых десяти простых чисел (начиная с 3) и вывод на консоль

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

выводит только 7 и 11. только начинаю ассемблер изучать. подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем тут дело. и да, с выводом массива я тоже не могу разобраться пока, поэтому прямо из регистра и передаю.

```
;программа ищет 10 простых чисел и выводит их на консоль
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc     ;wsprintf
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib      ;wsprintf
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
BSIZE equ 15
SSIZE equ 10

.data
    ifmt BYTE "%d",0
    buf BYTE BSIZE dup(?)
    stdout DWORD ?
    cWritten DWORD ?
    crlf BYTE 0dh, 0ah
.data?
    PrimeNumbers DWORD SSIZE dup(?)
.code
start:
mov ebx, 3         ;begin from number 3
mov edi, 0         ;0 element of array
mov ebp, 0         ;counter of primes
nxtdig:
    mov edx, 0     ;edx:eax число
    mov eax, ebx
    mov ecx, ebx   ;счетчик цикла
    sub ecx, 2     ;число проверок меньше проверяемого числа на 2
    mov esi, 2     ;начинаем с деления на 2
nxtpr:
    div esi
    cmp edx, 0     ;сравниваем остаток с 0
    jz skip        ;да - идем к след.проверке
    mov edx, 0     ;no ->
    mov eax, ebx   ;восстан число в edx:eax
    inc esi        ;высчитываем след число для деления
    loop nxtpr     ;проверка edx и конец итерации цикла

mov PrimeNumbers[edi], ebx    ;если не на что уже делить (ecx = 0)

invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE            ;вывод числа на консоль
mov stdout, ebx
invoke wsprintf, ADDR buf, ADDR ifmt, ebx      ;форматирование числа для вывода
invoke WriteConsoleA, stdout, ADDR buf,      ;вывод числа
        BSIZE, ADDR cWritten, NULL
invoke WriteConsoleA, stdout, ADDR crlf, 2,
            ADDR cWritten, NULL                ; вывод новая строка (числа в столбик)

inc ebp             ;увеличиваем счетчик простых чисел
cmp ebp, SSIZE      ;найдено ли нужное кол-во простых? (10)
jz done             ;да - выходим

add edi, 4          ;нет - след элем массива

skip:
    inc ebx             ;увеличиваем - переходим 
    jmp nxtdig          ;к следующему числу для проверки
done:
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

Comment: А вы пользовались отладчиком?

Comment: пробую им пользоваться) дело в том, что семерка вместо тройки помещается в eax после вызова StdHandle. проблема, как мне кажется, именно в том, как у меня вывод организован. но это только мое скромное предположение...

Comment: пардон, про eax ерунда сейчас была. я-то передаю ebx, который остается "непорченным".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

короче говоря, всего-то надо было не из ebx помещать в stdout, а из EAX. так эмпирически мы выяснили, что в переменную эту для вывода (а явно еще и для ввода, и для открытия файла) перемещать можно только из него.

```
invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE            ;вывод числа на консоль
mov stdout, eax
invoke wsprintf, ADDR buf, ADDR ifmt, ebx      ;форматирование числа для вывода
invoke WriteConsoleA, stdout, ADDR buf,      ;вывод числа
        BSIZE, ADDR cWritten, NULL
invoke WriteConsoleA, stdout, ADDR crlf, 2,
            ADDR cWritten, NULL                ; вывод новая строка (числа в столбик)
```

и таки вопрос к знающим остается: а как организовать вывод массива PrimeNumbers? а то он создается, но не используется, с таким же успехом его можно и не создавать. помещать каждый элемент в EAX предварительно? вряд ли.

Answer (score 0):

на мой взгляд ошибка тут

```
 sub ecx, 2     ;число проверок меньше проверяемого числа на 2
```

а должно быть = ecx/2

Comment: Не думаю что это критично.

Comment: @santavital, да, так лучше и быстрее, но 7 там все равно появится...